# What will be the base href link for an url containing parameter for an angular 6 project in liver server?

Tags: angular6

I need to open the base href link for the 1st page load working with Angular 6 like

xyz.com/anexure/5.

This is working fine in my localhost.But this is not working in live server.

In Live server I folder structure like

xyz.com/annexture/annextureform

Inside the ***annextureform*** folder I have the angular project

**index.html**

base href ="xyz.com/annexture/annextureform/"

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/annexture/:id', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path: 'annexture/:id', component: AnnextureformComponent}
];
```

What changes I have to make in htaccess file for the angular project?

Answer (score 0):

If u deploy the project inside some other folder, the changes you need to make are:

Just folder names and not the domain folder name

**base href="annexture/annextureform/"**

Comment: I have created an htaccss file also inside the angular project. Shall I need that?

Comment: The above solution is Not working.Page showing nothing.

Comment: Can u just copy paste the errors from console.... No need for htaccess